# What is the economic behaviour of a uniswap pool as all its members leave?

Tags: economics, uniswap

I bought some defi tokens using uniswap. As I understand it, my ETH is now part of a pool. The price of the token changes according to `a*b=k` as people swap in and out of it, or by arbitrage.

Okay, but what if everyone leaves the pool when my back is turned?

What are the economics if everyone leaves one by one and I am the last person left? Is there a risk of getting stuck?

Comment: Are you talking about the perspective of a liquidity provider or a trader? It sounds like you might be mixing up the two roles.

Comment: I may well be. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: By purchasing tokens on Uniswap, your money becomes part of the pool, that is correct. But you already received the other side of tokens as return, so whatever happens afterwards doesn't affect you. Maybe this helps: https://medium.com/@pintail/uniswap-a-good-deal-for-liquidity-providers-104c0b6816f2?